# Should I be entering "0" or "-0-" on my 1040 form?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, form-1040

There are several instances on the instructions for "year-2018" 1040 form that indicate to fill in a "-0-". When filling out this form, should I really be entering a "-0-" or should I be entering a "0"?

I assume this form is processed electronically and don't want it to be flagged because I am using the wrong notation.

Comment: Note that "-0-" is intended to prevent modification by anyone in the chain of custody, but modification of an electronic record does not overprint the old value, and so there is no useful purpose to "-0-".  Whether there's a useless requirement, I cannot say.

Comment: @BenVoigt fixed.

Comment: You shouldn't be entertaining anything on a paper 1040 unless you're in the very very small minority of taxpayers who are forced to file manually. You should be e-filing. All returns are ultimately e-filed - if you submit a paper return, not only do you give *yourself* the chance to make a mistake, you give the temp workers in Austin and other cities the chance to make an error. Don't file on paper unless you really really have to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you enter "0" or "-0-".

The [instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi) usually say "enter -0-".  However, this is as much for making the instructions more legible as for anything on the actual form.  The IRS scanners will be able to interpret either "0" or "-0-" as zero.  In addition, you can also leave 0-value lines blank.

I have used both TurboTax and H&R Block tax software in the past several years, and have always printed and mailed my tax return.  Both of these software programs use either "0" or leave lines blank (Both techniques are done on the same return by both programs).  In no instance have I seen either program print a "-0-" in a line on any tax form.

Comment: Yes. I've used TurboTax and H&R and I see the same thing: zero entries are usually left blank. Occasionally they put "0". I've never seen them put "-0-". It's been years since I did taxes by hand with a pen, but when I did, I always put blank or "0", never "-0-".

Comment: Yes, I've read instructions that indicate that you should leave "zeros" blank. But this is the first time I recall the instructions explicitly saying to enter a zero.

Comment: @Izzo The instructions have used the phrase "enter -0-" for at least 20 years. ([PDF of 1998's Form 1040 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/i1040--1998.pdf))

Comment: What? You use a program to do your tax and then PRINT it and send it in? Hallelujah for the Dutch case. Online tax returns for many years now. In many cases you only have to check them against what they know already (mandatory filing by employers and banks). But be careful out there! Make sure you get your deductions. Again, just enter it online and presto!

Comment: @PaulPalmpje: You *can* e-file in the USA too, with a few exceptions.  But you have no way to know what information actually got sent, so the paranoid may prefer to use the tax software to generate a PDF, inspect that, print and mail it.  Tree pulp can be buggy too, but those bugs are a lot less likely to go unnoticed ;)